# Problems setting up a Gmail account in MS Outlook for macOS

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, gmail, mac-mini

- I am using a Mac mini M1 running macOS 11.2.1 with MS Outlook for Mac 16.46.
- I am trying to add a Gmail or GSuite account to MS Outlook.
- A wizard opens to enter the email address.
- Then a browser window opens and asks me to sign in to my account and grant permissions to Outlook
- After signing in and clicking "Allow", I expect the process to move back to Outlook

But the browser just displays:

```
Cannot GET /api/googleoauthredir/com.microsoft.office.outlook:/mac/google/oauth2redirect
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to my experience, I could configure my gmail normally in my outlook for mac(version 16.46), as a suggestion, maybe you could try to [reset your desktop client preferences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/outlook-for-mac/useful-tools#outlookresetpreferences) If that's invalid, we could also try to add your account in a [new profile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-profiles-or-identities-in-outlook-for-mac-fed2a955-74df-4a24-bef6-78a426958c4c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) to check.

Comment: It’s not clear to me how Outlook is involved in this question, or at what point in what process the error occurs.  I presume that you have a Gmail account that you can use directly (from a browser), but if you *stated* this, people wouldn’t have to guess.  Is there anything unusual about that Gmail account? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Jade thank you for the suggestions. It is a brand new macOS install with a new Outlook install that never had an account set up.

Answer (score 0):

After just editing my question, it now worked.

So it was probably a server problem on Microsoft's or Google's end.

Also, yesterday someone [posted the same problem on a German forum](https://www.macuser.de/threads/anmeldung-in-outlook-nicht-moeglich-macbook-m1.873835/).

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, it's recommended to mark your post as answer to close this thread normally :)